# swagger-autogen: How to add multiple servers?

Tags: swagger

How to add multiple servers to swagger with `swagger-autogen`?

the documentation is providing only one host [here](https://github.com/davibaltar/swagger-autogen#openapi-3x:%7E:text=host%3A%20%27%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20by%20default%3A%20%27localhost%3A3000%27)

I want to do something like that:

```js
const doc = {
  .
  .
  hosts: ['localhost:3000', 'localhost:5000'],
  .
  .
};
```

but when I did it, the base URL became `http://localhost:3000localhost:5000/`

is there any way to add multiple servers to `swagger-autogen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, there is a way:

1. Enable the OpenAPI v3 in the options [here](https://github.com/davibaltar/swagger-autogen#openapi-3x:%7E:text=const%20swaggerAutogen%20%3D%20require(%27swagger%2Dautogen%27)(%7Bopenapi%3A%20%273.0.0%27%7D))

```js
const swaggerAutogen = require('swagger-autogen')({openapi: '3.0.0'});
```

2. Remove `host`, `basePath`, and `schemes` from object `doc`
3. Add the following array instead:

```js
const doc = {
  .
  .
  servers: [
    {
      url: "http://localhost:3000/",
      description: "main server"
    },
    {
      url: "http://localhost:5000/",
      description: "the other server"
    }
  ],
  .
  .
};
```

it didn't exist in the documentation, but it works since the object `doc` is converted into a JSON object inside the file named `swagger-output.json`